# ПОМОГИТЕ ПЖ проверить что в массиве все элементы положительны программа должна вывести на экран один раз слово Да или Нет

Tags: python

проверить что в массиве все элементы положительны программа должна вывести на экран один раз слово Да или Нет

```
from random import randint
a=[randint(1,10)for i in range (5)]

print(a)

d = 0

while d < 5:
  if a[d]//1<0:
    print('да')
  else:
    print('нет')
  a[d]=a[d+1]
  d+=1
print(a)
```

Comment: `if a[d]//1<0:` и `a[d]=a[d+1]` - что это и зачем?

Comment: работа друга  я хз можете помочь

Comment: Не самый оптимальный, но в одну строку: `print(sum([i for i in arr if i < 0]) == 0)`. Ещё один вариант: `print(len([i for i in arr if i < 0]) == 0)`

Comment: можете скинуть целый код)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
all(map(lambda i: i > 0, your_arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random 

a = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range (5)]

print(a)

if all(a) > 0:
    print('да')

else:
    print('нет')
```

Держи, надеюсь я правильно тебя понял

Ещё хотел уточнить, зачем тебе `if a[d]//1<0:` и `a[d]=a[d+1]`?

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли и ваш код можно переписать лучше ;)

Comment: если поставить вместо 1 10 -5 5 код плохо считает